# RegEx pattern returning all words except those in parenthesis

Tags: regex

I have a text of the form:

> können {konnte, gekonnt} Verb

And I want to get a match for all words in it that are not in parenthesis. That means:

> können = 1st match, Verb = 2nd match

Unfortunately I still don't get the knock of regular expression. There is a lot of testing possibility but not much help for creation unless you want to read a book.

I will use them in Java or Python.

Comment: replace `/\{[^}]*\}/` with nothing in your input string, then simply get your matches...

Comment: Thanks, all answers are working. I marked one as answer although all helped me. I really need to get into regular expressions better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python you could do this:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'(?:\{.*?\})?([^{}]+)', re.UNICODE)
print 'Matches: %r' % regex.findall(u'können {konnte, gekonnt} Verb')
```

Result:

```
Matches: [u'können ', u' Verb']
```

Although I would recommend simply replacing everything between `{` and `}` like so:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'\{.*?\}', re.UNICODE)
print 'Output string: %r' % regex.sub('', u'können {konnte, gekonnt} Verb')
```

Result:

```
Output string: u'können  Verb'
```

Answer (score 1):

A regex SPLIT using this pattern will do the job:

```
(\s+|\s*{[^}]*\}\s*)
```

and ignore any empty value.